# C: Multiple timers

Tags: c

I want to have more than two timers. Each timer has its own precision. I have read that I can just have one timer, is this accurate? Is there any way to have more than one?

Comment: What operating system? What language?

Comment: What hardware? There are platforms with more than one timer...

Comment: Egregiously underspecified. @Amir, if you will kindly answer the question that have been put to you about what type of system you are running on this question can be reopened...

Answer (score 2):

You can multiplex a single timer to simulate multiple timers.

You will need program the real timer to go off at the GCD (greatest common denominator) of the times you require:

For example:

timer1 - every 12 seconds

timer2 - every 18 seconds

GCD(12,18) = 6

realtimer - every 6 seconds

```
if (time % 12 == 0)
{
  invoke_timer_1();
} 
if (time % 18 == 0)
{
  invoke_timer_2();
}
// if neither, do nothing
```

Comment: This is a nice work-around for situation where there is no OS or hardware support.